# create custom directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have done it correctly by taking reference fro, official docs of angularjs.
But in directive's link method, when I set the validity using `$setValidity()` method, it does not reflects in view part using `{{formname.controlname.$error.validationErrorKey}}`

Please help me to track the error, or mistake that I am doing.

Thanks in advance

```html
<form name="form" novalidate>
    URL <input  type="text" ng-model="myURL" name="myURL" my-url /> {{form.myURL.$error.myUrlError}}
    <span class="errorMessage" ng-show="form.myURL.$dirty && form.myURL.$error.myUrlError">
       please enter correct url
    </span>
</form>
```

```js
validationModule.directive("myUrl", function($window) {    
    //return Directive Definition Object (DDO)
    return{
        restrict:"A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.bind('blur',function() {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(ctrl.$viewValue)) {
                    console.log('isEMpty-' + new Date());
                    ctrl.$setValidity("myUrlError", true);
                } else {
                    var URL_REGEXP= /https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}/;
                    if (URL_REGEXP.test(ctrl.$viewValue)) {
                        console.log("valid-" + new Date());
                        ctrl.$setValidity("myUrlError", true);
                    } else {
                        console.log("invalid-" + new Date());
                        ctrl.$setValidity("myUrlError", false);
                    }
                }
            }); //end if 'blur' event listener  
        }//end of link function
    };//end of DDO      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> use
>
> ```
> scope.$apply( attrs.my-url);
> ```
>
> inside your blur event i.e
>
> ```
> element.bind('blur', function () {
>                     scope.$apply( attrs.attrs.my-url );
>                 }
>             });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
elm.bind('blur',function(){
```

Angular know nothing about jquery events. They do not rise digest run. So you have to run it manualy by $scope.$applyAsync()

[Here you can read more about applyAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 0):

In your sample you check if input is empty and if correspond to a pattern. I think your approach is so difficult for this feature.
I recommend to you to see attribute [ng-required](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) and [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) to do that. It's a more simple way i think

Here a plunker to illustrate it : https://plnkr.co/edit/pRqXfsjduvQGuRwDBuUL?p=preview

```
 URL <input  type="text" ng-model="myURL" name="myURL" required="true" ng-pattern="/https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}/" /> {{form.myURL.$error}}
```

Another way is to create a custom validator : https://plnkr.co/edit/1hFMlB2IzuWpV7v8TOUP?p=preview

```
ctrl.$validators.myUrlValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            console.log('vbalidate')
            if(!viewValue || viewValue == "") {
              return false;
            }
            if(!URL_REGEXP.test(viewValue)){
              return false;
            }
            return true
          }
```